# Animation Nodes - Offset object location

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to Offset the location of grouped objects with a falloff object. I cannot use an instancer because in the final project all the objects are different.

Here is the basic setup : an empty which is the object falloff and 3 cubes (for testing purpose).

[image]

The goal is to have the cubes go up when the empty is moved near them.

Here is what I tried :
[image]

The issue is that all the 3 cubes are moving in the same time and I'd like them to move one by one, slightly after another.

The same setup works well with a text for example. Here an example with text at mid move of the object offset controler :
[image]

As you can see the Z value is different for each object.

Same position off the falloff controler but back with the 3 cubes :
[image]

It seems that when using functions of Animation nodes to generate objects, it sets the value "Initial transforms" which is then used to offset. But when I use my object this "Initial transforms" value are at zero, the same for all of 3 cubes and thus the offset is the same in the same time when the controller is moved...

I'm just a beginner with Animation Nodes so maybe I miss something obvious...

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a loop for all group objects?

Comment: I tried it but had difficulties to make it work with the falloff... And now I found the solution to update the Initial Transforms information :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I find the solution, you can update the "Initial Transforms" value. To do that:

1. Select the "Object ID key" node
2. Select the object that need to have the Initial Transforms update
3. In the Tool panel of the 3D view, go the the AN tab
4. Click on "From Current Transforms"

[image]

Repeat for each object and it works!

Comment: Accept your answer if it answers your question.