# Animation Nodes: How to create a stagger-to effect for pre-existing objects (no instancing)?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to create a stagger-to effect for pre-existing objects.
I have five placeholder objects like so:
[image]

But when I set up the animation nodes, all object transformations are reset to 0,0,0:
[image]

The rotation animation does still work as expected, but without taking into account the original transformation of the objects.

This issue does not happen when working with the Separate Text Objects node instead of the Create Object List node. In that case, each objects position is retained:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your objects have initial transforms? Can you investigate the output of the ID node and see what is there?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109017/23161

As Omar Ahmad pointed out in the comment, the objects need to have AN initial transforms set.